# What's the correct English term for this old typesetting technique?

Tags: typography, terminology, typesetting

I am building up a typography glossary and I'm looking for the name of this old typographic technique. I have seen it now and then since I was a kid. It was common for more than some eighty years ago, a lot before the advent of digital typesetting. It was used when saving up space was a must, as in glossaries, dictionaries or books with a lot of text.

In this procedure, a line's end is continued at the blank end of the previous line preceded by an opening square bracket, instead of continuing it by adding a line, as it would normally happen. I hope the attached image illuminates the concept.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I've found three sources mentioning this technique.

---

[Beadnell, Henry: *A guide to typography, in two parts, literary and practica*, 1859, p. 165-166:](https://archive.org/details/guidetotypograph00beadrich/page/n183/mode/2up)

[image]

---

[De Vinne, Theodore Low: *The practice of typography; modern methods of book composition*, 1904, p. 148:](https://archive.org/details/practicetypogra00vinngoog/page/n166/mode/2up)

[image]

---

[De Vinne, Theodore Low: *The practice of typography; correct composition*, 1910, p. 278:](https://archive.org/details/typogr00devipracticeofrich/page/278/mode/2up)

[image]

---

Sadly, none of these books mentions a proper term for the technique (and they all seem to advice against using it if avoidable).

In *The practice of typography; correct composition*, De Vinne uses the expression: **"bracketing in a previous line of a word too long for the line"**, which is the closest thing to a name I can find.

Comment: Idunno bracketing previous line sounds like a good term

Comment: Kind of find it funny that *where* that "[and" should fall *appears* to be subjective. If after "Knives", then why not before "Scissors"? if not after "Knives" then where? --- Rhetorical.. not expecting you to know this. 

Comment: @Scott, that *is* kinda strange. Didn't even notice ... hmmm. Ah! Searching for the verse reveals that it's from the poem ["The Friend of Humanity and the Knife-grinder"](https://www.bartleby.com/333/226.html) and it seems that the author deliberately placed a line-break before "Scissors", so the "bracketing" is done to maintain the original line-breaks. Also see [this](http://www.clker.com/cliparts/2/f/7/9/1261672096282207115mmtiae.png).

Comment: Makes sense... someone was being a bit *too* fastidious though, I think. The line breaks in that original don't *appear* to be anything more than due to the end of spacing provided for the previous line. To me it appears the important part was 3 full lines, then one small right justified line. Not *where* the breaks were specifically. I mean the original wasn't line-for-line center justified either. So break one format but cause confusion by trying to retain another... meh.. I'm just rambling :)

Comment: @Scott, true. And this whole "bracketing" method is kinda crazy. Never seen it before I saw this question. It's like `float: left` in css going terribly wrong.

Comment: @Wolff im pretty sure you have seen it in handwriting though where a user uses a crooked line to cram up a bit more text. Never seen it in movable type untill now but its the same concept.

Comment: @joojaa, hehe yeah. When I take notes by hand this often happens. Also writing vertically down the right side of the paper when I run out of horizontal space. 

Comment: Thank you, Wolff. Even though I have not yet found a single term to name it, this helps.

Comment: You're welcome @Mosh. I'm still searching! It would be fun to solve this, but perhaps there simply isn't a term (which would be almost impossible to be certain about).

Comment: I have building a typographical glossary (in Spansish) for many years now. If I don't find a term, I guess I will try to create one. : )

Comment: @Mosh, in Spanish? Ah. Perhaps you can use [this link](https://www.rae.es/dpd/corchete) a user posted in the chat yesterday.

Comment: @Wolff: Thanks, although the term explained also does not mention a name for the square bracket in such context...